# angular 2 on a computer without internet

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to start developing with angular2 and angular-cli on a computer that is NOT connected to the internet.

on my connected computer, i've installed angular-cli .
what do i need to copy (and from where) to a DOK in order to move it to the disconnected computer?

Answer (score 1):

I've started to use VERDACCIO, which is  a fork from the SINOPOA project on github.

this gives me great support to have a local NPM inside a network which is not connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I would get the angular2-seed project working on your regular computer first.  Then copy the entire directory structure and all files to the non-connected computer.

Comment: that's what i thought... but what about all the npm modules that are installed globally ? (angular-cli) etc ... copy them from the %AppData folder  to the destination computer ? even Angular2 is installed there...

Comment: I would copy the npm install exe, and the packages to install onto a disk, then install npm and the packages on the non-connected computer.

Comment: ok figured it out.
besides the npm installer, i've copied the entire seed folder (around 30k files ! because of angular-cli) and also the entire NPM folder under my user account c:\users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NPM